# Event bubling using hostevent listener

Tags: angular

I have built a directive which subscribes the keyboard event using host event listener. When escape key is pressed I am firing an output event like this

```
    @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(kbdEvent: KeyboardEvent) {
       if (kbdEvent.keyCode === 27) {
            this.CloseEvent.emit();
       }
    }
```

I have this directive for child elements. When escape key is pressed I want to fire the output event only for the newly subscribed elements. The problem is when I click on escape key the event is fired based on hierarchical order. I have made a demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/FfnHAtxl2zcHsu0JilKt

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add Multiple Child Elements
2. Click On Escape it close all elements

Expected behavior:

1. When Escape key is clicked on the last added child element event needs to be fired

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is... I press escape and they all close, I press delete and the adjacent one closes?

Comment: User has two options to remove a added child by clicking on delete button or escape.When I click on escape key you can see all the added child being removed.I want the recently added element only to be removed not all

Comment: And by recently you mean the last 1 which was added?

Comment: @zze yeah the last added one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to send the `KeyboardEvent` with the `close` event. You can then check if the event has `defaultPrevented` set to true, if not, execute the deletion and `preventDefault`.

I've made some optimizations. You can just use the `'document:keyup.ESC'` binding, and you can immediately set `(close)` and it will use the `CloseDirective`

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AwwZGe4WhdhMYaSRXJd2?p=preview)

**my-app**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h4>Add Multiple Child And Click On Escape key</h4><br>
    <div *ngFor="let child of childArray;let i = index">
      <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
          <my-chid (close)="onClose($event)" [index]="child"></my-chid>
          <button (click)="deleteChild(i)">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="addChild()">Add Child</button>
  `,
})
export class App {

  childArray: any[] = [];

  addChild(): void {
    this.childArray.push(this.childArray.length);
  }

  onClose(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.deleteChild(this.childArray.length - 1);
    }
  }

  deleteChild(index: number): void {
    this.childArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

**my-child**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-chid',
  template: `
    <div>
       I am child {{index}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyChild {

  @Input()
  public index: number; 

}
```

**close directive**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[close]'
})
export class CloseDirective {

    @Output() close: EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent> = new EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent>();

    @HostListener('document:keyup.ESC', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(kbdEvent: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.close.emit(kbdEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @PierreDuc .Having a small issue with the above code.When i click on escape key it actually removes the first added element rather than last added element.Can you people tell me what can i do make it work

Comment: I've updated my answer. My bad there, I forgot to add that it should remove the last index of the array. Ill update the plnkr as well

Comment: Thank you it really solved my problem. I am curious to know whether it is possible to make event to fire from last subscribed element.I mean when ever i add a child element the directive subscribes to keyboard escape key event why not make the last added element escape key event to fire first and then the rest?

Comment: because the `CloseDirective` is created 3 times. You could try and make a `service` on where you register from the directive, and let that handle the escape event, and only send it to the last directive registered